# DataGridView.Editmode = EditOnEnter. How to Select the row to Delete it?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview

When I use EditMode = EditOnEnter, The cell enter on editmode when I select the row.

It is hard to user to select the RowSelector to Delete the row.

do you know any Trick ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I Try this Trick:

If the user clicks on a row header, change the EditMode to `EditOnKeystrokeOrF2`and end the edit.

If the user clicks somewhere else, change the EditMode to `EditOnEnter`and begin the edit.

---

```
Private Sub dgv2_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv2.CellClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = -1 Then
       dgv2.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystrokeOrF2
       dgv2.EndEdit()
    ElseIf dgv2.EditMode <> DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter Then
       dgv2.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
       dgv2.BeginEdit(False)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This was really useful, I combined this with the 'CellPreviewKeyDown' event, allowing to leave the cell edit mode pressing ESC key

Comment: I also found this useful, but if there was a cell already in edit mode, and I selected more than one row to delete, it left one of the rows in edit mode, so deleting didnt work again. I then moved this code to the `CellMouseUp` event and it worked just how I wanted. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

You should understand that your program can't really read user's thought and understand when enter edit mode but when don't this.

User can press Escape key to cancel edit mode, then row can be deleted. Also you may choose other DataGridViewEditMode (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridvieweditmode.aspx ), for instance DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke, or EditOnKeystrokeOrF2 that both are good from the usability point of view.

Comment: I know all other modes. Users want Excel mode like. I use EditOnEnter only on Frequent used DGV. I know how to delete a row, but instruct each user on this behavior ....
Esc Key can cancel edit, but on this mode re-Enter on Edit Mode. I do´nt understand why selecting the RowSelector, do´nt ends Edit mode. A solution is  move cursor to a not editable cell.

Answer (score 0):

This really needs to be done on MouseDown. Cell Click events fire on MouseUp:

```
Private Sub ProductsGrid_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ProductsGrid.MouseDown
    Dim grid = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim info = grid.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)

    If into.Type = DataGridViewHitTestType.RowHeader OrElse info.Type = DataGridViewHitTestType.TopLeftHeader Then
        grid.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystrokeOrF2
        grid.EndEdit()
    ElseIf grid.EditMode <> DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter Then
        grid.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
    End If
End Sub
```

There is more that needs to be done as well, including handling Tab Key behaviour. Such behaviour (and the above modification) are probably best done in a user control which inherits DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the focus to the parent control. That will force the cell to end editing without having to change the mode itself.

For example this snippet will leave the edit mode if you select more then one cell.

```
protected override void OnSelectionChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSelectionChanged(e);

    if (SelectedCells.Count > 1)
    {
        // leave edit mode
        Parent?.Focus();
    }
}
```